# Pandas group-by error duplicate axis but no duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas

I've done this code:

```
df[['GL','Libelle']]=df['index'].str.split(' ',1,expand=True)

# Sort by GL, Date
df.sort_values(by=['GL', 'Class','month'], inplace=True)

# add columun with diff by month
df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'])
df["diff"] = df.groupby(['GL','Class','month'])['value'].diff().fillna(df['value'])
```

my pandas df is like this:
index       object

Class       object

value      float64

glid        object

month       object

GL          object

Libelle     object

and this is sample:
[image]

Could you explain with I have this error ?
"cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" on line df["diff"] = df.groupby(['GL','Class','month'])['value'].diff().fillna(df['value'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, this error arises when you try to join or assign to a column when the index(row or column names) has duplicate values. If I'm understanding correctly, you are trying to join the column, so check if your rows have duplicate values. Also, check your original dataframe. It may possible that the duplicate is present in your original dataframe.

To find the duplicates in the original index, do this:
`df[df.index.duplicated()]`

If you accidentally have created a duplicate column then remove it. This will solve your error.